# nested select - SQL-query

Tags: mysql, sql, select

In my MySQL DB I have a table like this

```
| - value - | - date -   |
|------------------------|
| 1         | 01.01.2016 |
| 2         | 02.01.2016 |
| 3         | 04.02.2016 |
| 5         | 01.01.2017 |
| 1         | 02.01.2017 |
| 5         | 04.02.2017 |
```

As result, I would like to have a value differences of rows with equal dates (regarding only the day and the month).

So basically I want this as result:

```
| - value - | - date -   |
|------------------------|
| 1 - 4     | 01.01      |
| 2 - 1     | 02.01      |
| 3 - 5     | 04.02      |
```

How can I do it in SQL? I can use a nested SELECT to get data of one year like this:

```
SELECT col FROM (
SELECT value,date FROM Table 
WHERE date BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31'
) tab1
```

Now I would have to add the 2017 year data - but if I just write `FROM (SELECT ...) tab1, (SELECT ...) tab2` It will be a "cross prodcut" - And the numbers won't add up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd create two subqueries, one for 2016 and one for 2017, and then join them:

```
SELECT CONCAT(v16, ' - ', v17)
FROM   (SELECT value AS v16, date AS d16
        FROM   mytable
        WHERE  YEAR(date) = 2016) a
JOIN   (SELECT value AS v17, date AS d17
        FROM   mytable
        WHERE  YEAR(date) = 2017) b ON MONTH(d16) = MONTH(d17) AND
                                       DAY(d16) = DAY(d17)
```

Comment: So do I understand it right, that one can only JOIN...? It seems logical that you join them by the day/month-date.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(value SEPARATOR '-'),DATE_FORMAT(date,'%m-%d')as date 
FROM table GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date,'%m-%d');
```

Comment: I don't quite get the `GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT('2000-07-10','%m-%d')` part. Shouldn't it be `GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date,'%m-%d')`  ? this would mean, that you group by the day/month and then you can do stuff with this - I could also use `SUM` instead of `GROUP_CONCAT` I suppose